# Check whether two JavaScript arrays are equal, using basic library only

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that takes in two arrays and a test name and outputs statements (console.log) saying whether the two arrays are equal. I don't want to convert the arrays to strings or use non-core libraries to do this. I am also new to writing JS so I wanted to get a code review here.

```
Usage: FAILURE CASE:
var expected = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
var actual = [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]; 
assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, 'generates first 7 Fibonacci 
numbers');

console output:
 FAILED [generates first 7 Fibonacci numbers] Expected "1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 
8, 13", but got "2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34"
```

```js
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName) {

  var lengthsEqual = (actual.length === expected.length)
  var contentsEqual = true
  for (var i=0; i<actual.length; i++)
  {
    if (actual[i] !== expected[i]) contentsEqual=false
  }
  if(contentsEqual && lengthsEqual){
   console.log("passed")
  }
  else{
    console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected "' + expected + '", but got "' + actual + '"');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function should be dedicated to its functionality. Have all the printing done externally. You don't need `testName` as a parameter.
2. Have your function return `true` or `false`. It's much more useful and reusable that way. Having it return also allows you to exit the function early if you know the arrays are not equal. For example:

   ```
   function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected) {
       if (actual.length !== expected.length) {
           return false;
       }
       ...
   ```
3. If this is for something like unit testing, you should use a unit test library to like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) or [Qunit](https://qunitjs.com/) to validate the behavior of the function.
4. What data types are you dealing with? Are you only concerned with numbers? Do you want strict type checking and/or null checking?

If you're only concerned with validating arrays of numbers and you know the bounds of the input, you can easily rewrite your function like so:

```
    function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected) {
        if (actual.length !== expected.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; ++i) {
            if (actual[i] !== expected[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For one thing, it would good practice to end your lines of code with `;`.

Also, you did not enclose `contentsEqual=false` in brackets.

It is not clear if you called the `function assertArrays`.  Functions do not run automatically.

It would be better if the `for` construct only ran while `lengthseq` and `contentEqual` are true.

Comment: Ending lines of code with `;` is completely optional and depends on the programmer. Enclosing with brackets is also completely optional for one-liners. We can assume the function is called, there's no need to put it in the code. What are you referring to in your 4th comment?

Comment: @omgimanerd - there are lots of cases when a semicolon really is required. even when it's not required, it's still required, but the javascript interpreter inserts them automatically. he is absolutely correct in saying they're best practice.

Comment: The most important case is for when a semicolon is required is the separation of function declarations, documented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596/5792737). Given the context of the question, suggesting that semicolons are required is irrelevant since best practice is subjective as well, OP might be using the [StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/) convention or a similar convention.

Comment: At the end of the post they suggested a code review.  that was what i had to offer